# Place x number of points equidistant from each other on a circle segment circumference

Tags: geometry

So I have a circle segment, a 90 degrees part of a circle, so 1/4 of the circle. I know the radius and I want to place an x number of points spread out evenly on the circumference. How can I achieve that using a formula?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPCQ7.png)

Comment: How is it only possible for only 3 points

Comment: I have added a visualisation to make it more clear

Comment: What do you mean by equidistant? Is every point the same distant from every other point? or just its neighbors?

Comment: Just neighbors, sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Fixed, added visualisation too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that a circle is determined by $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle, 
$0\leq\theta<2\pi$, and $\theta$ is the angle made by the x-axis and the line connecting the point on the circle and the origin. In the way that you want, the formula is $$x_k=r\cos\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)},~y_k=r\sin\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}$$ where $n$ is the number of points and $(x_k,y_k)$ is the $k^{th}$ point on the segment (and thus $1\leq k\leq n$). This places all the points in the first quadrant. To offset the points, merely add a constant term to the arguments of the sine and cosine.

e.g. $$x_k=r\cos\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg),~y_k=r\sin\bigg(\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}-\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$

rotates the points a quarter-turn clockwise, moving them into the $4^{th}$ qudrant as shown in the picture you gave.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier if the arc chosen is in the 1st quadrant.

[image]

Then, $(x_k, y_k) = (r \cos (\dfrac {k \pi}{2(n + 1)}), r \sin (\dfrac {k \pi}{2(n + 1)}))$.